# Can we measure without collapsing (too much) the wave function, according to decoherence theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, observables, wavefunction-collapse, decoherence

According to decoherence theory, the collapse of the wave function is a continuous process due to interaction with environment.
In a measure, there are interactions with photons (for example).

Can we measure with very few photons so that the wave function doesn't collapse [too much]?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is specifically related to decoherence theory, but are you asking for [weak measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_measurement)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I don't think it is *specifically*  related to decoherence theory, I ask a question *about* decoherence theory. If we replace "according to decoherence theory" by "according to Copenhagen interpretation", then the answer is *no* by definition. So for the question to be relevant, we need to assume an alternative to Copenhagen interpretation. Anyway, I did not have "weak measurement" in mind when I wrote this post, but it should be close to "measure with very few photons".